# How to preserve formatting of textshape format of powerpoint slide using c#

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint, office-interop

I am using c# interop to get page content of shape text using below code:

```
var textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
var text = textRange.Text;
```

where text contains text of textshape. But all formatting gone. :(

We modify the content using our own editor and create ppt using the changed content:

```
string strToReplace = StripTagsRegex(xmlTempNode.InnerText);
strToReplace = strToReplace.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strToReplace;//load new text to shape
```

I am getting the required text in final output(i.e. generated ppt).But all alignments,pragraphs,formatting are gone. Is there any way to preserve it??

Thanks for stopping by...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace text within a PowerPoint shape and preserve the formatting, use PowerPoint's own Replace method.

In VBA:

```
With Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
  .Replace "this text", "with this text"
End With
```

Comment: :thanks for reply steve. But i am not sure that which part of text is modified by the user.he might add new content or replace/delete old content.

Comment: In that case, if some of the text is formatted differently from the rest, it's impossible to know which bits of the replaced text get what formatting.  If the entire text box is to retain the same formatting, try using the Pickup method on the shape to grab the formatting and after the text has changed, use Apply to reapply it.  If that doesn't work, you may need to store all of the formatting that you want to retain then apply it after replacing the text.

Comment: is it possible to get/set the html of ppt slide and then ill use it in editor to make changes. and finally ill use that html to create the slide.is it possible??

Comment: PPTX files are really ZIP files with XML and other components held within it.  In theory, you can extract the xml for the slide you're editing, modify it and put it back into the file.  I doubt you can do this while the file itself is open, but perhaps you don't need to do that.  You'll still be faced with the same problem.  If some of the text you started with is bold and some of it is in another font that the rest, and you replace it with new text, how will you know which bits get bolded/which bits get which font, etc?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you need to do and how complex the formatting you need to preserve is.  If preserving the overall formatting of the text is enough (ie, possibly losing any formatting changes for individual words/letters within the text) then it's fairly simple.  And you can get the formatting for any given section of the text by iterating through its .Runs collection.  Each .Run(x) represents a change in formatting.

Comment: how is that possible that i have 3 paragraphs in 1 text shape whose formatting is gone completely gone while editing/modifying.so how will it map in end

Comment: It might be best if you showed an example of the text (with formatting) that you're trying to modify, and an example of the text you expect to replace it with.  And have you *tried* using the .Replace method?

Comment: will replace prevent the formatting??

and refer this presentation slide number 2 of this presentation https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprimelandrealestate.com.au%2FProperty%2520Management%2520Presentation.ppt&ei=dpzRUd3PN4aGrAfU2oGgAQ&usg=AFQjCNGShFBgp5f1IFHwkNLI-ZITeIu3ew&sig2=bYWb9nZOMKUfBlMlV4grLA&bvm=bv.48572450,d.bmk

Comment: "will replace prevent the formatting" ... ah.  You haven't tried it.  Suggest you do that.  And looking at a slide w/o knowing what you want to replace with what else is of little use.  Until you DEFINE the problem you're trying to solve, nobody can help you solve it.  Sorry ...